Confusion about Correct Answer for TFEU Article 288 and EU Decisions
I recently encountered a question regarding Article 288 TFEU and the nature of EU decisions, and I’m confused about the correct answer.
The question is as follows:
Which of the following statements is true/false?
I. Article 288 TFEU provides the legal basis for the EU to adopt a regulation in the field of the internal market.
II. EU decisions are always addressed to private individuals or companies, not to the EU Member States.
Options:


Statements I and II are true.
Statements I and II are false.
Statement I is true; statement II is false.
Statement I is false; statement II is true.


Based on my understanding:


Statement I should be true since Article 288 TFEU does allow the EU to adopt regulations.
Statement II should be false because decisions under Article 288 TFEU can be addressed to Member States, not just private individuals or companies.


Therefore, I believe Option 3 (Statement I is true; Statement II is false) should be the correct answer. However, my answer key says Option 2 (both statements are false) is correct, which has left me puzzled.
Can anyone clarify this? Is there something I’m missing, or could the answer key be incorrect?
Thanks in advance for your insights!

Art 288 TFEU defines what a "regulation" is, but doesn't say that the EU has competence to pass law concerning the "internal market". That competence is defined in Art 3 TFEU (for competition rules) and Art 4 TFEU (all other matters, as shared competence with member states).

@amon That sounds like an answer. why don't you post it as such.

Thank you very much, You're right. @amon
